# ViewModel очистить liveData

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewmodel, livedata

Подскажите как можно очистить все данные в viewModel
Есть первый фрагмент

```
class OneFragment :BaseViewBindingFragment<FragmentOneBinding>(FragmentOneBinding::inflate) {
val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels
//тут использую liveData
}
```

Сама ViewModel

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val filterRepository: FilterRepository,
    private val createOrderRepository: OrderCreationRepository
) : BaseViewModel<MyState>(MyState())
    private val _services1 = MutableLiveData<List<String>?>()
    val services1: LiveData<List<String>?>
        get() = _services1
        private val _services2 = MutableLiveData<List<String>?>()
    val services2: LiveData<List<String>?>
        get() = _services2

}
```

Фрагмент 2

```
class TwoFragment :BaseViewBindingFragment<FragmentTwoBinding>(FragmentTwoBinding::inflate) {
val viewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels
//тут использую liveData
}
```

Вот после этого у меня все данные во viewModel сохраняются. Как обнулить и MyState и liveData при переходе на третий фрагмент?

Comment: вместо `activityViewModels` в 3ем фрагменте использовать просто `viewModels`

Comment: Я же правильно это понимаю, если я указываю activityViewModels , то жизненный цикл viewmodel будет равняться жизненному циклу активити. Если в приложение single activity. Обращаясь к этой viewmodel , все данные будут сохраняться.